# select recursivo

Tags: mysql

Como realizar uma busca recursiva no estoque com receita, e rotorna o menor 'unico' valor dos ingredientes da receita para aviso do usuario, tenho as sequintes tabelas

```
`estoque`
id,nome,link,senha,saida
`receita`
id,nome,link,quantidade,porcao
`estoqueMovimento`
id,senha,entrada
```

no caso preciso que seja listado o estoque e check o link para montar a receita apenas para os itens que tenha link lembrando que pode conter receita dentro de receita

```
`estoque`
[0] => [id=>1, nome=>i1, link=>A156, saida=>10, senha=> das165]
[1] => [id=>2, nome=>i2, link=>A160, saida=>3, senha=> das164]
[2] => [id=>3, nome=>i3, link=>A157, saida=>4, senha=> das163]
[3] => [id=>4, nome=>i4, link=>A156, saida=>6, senha=> das162]
[4] => [id=>5, nome=>i5, link=>, saida=>1, senha=> das161]
[4] => [id=>6, nome=>i6, link=>, saida=>1, senha=> das160]
[5] => [id=>7, nome=>i7, link=>A161, saida=>3, senha=> das171]
`receita`
[0] => [id=>1, nome=>p1.1, link=>A156, quantidade=>10, porcao=>0.035]
[1] => [id=>2, nome=>p1.2, link=>A156, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.028]
[2] => [id=>3, nome=>p2.1, link=>A160, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.003]
[3] => [id=>4, nome=>p2.2, link=>A160, quantidade=>6, porcao=>0.025]
[4] => [id=>5, nome=>p2.3, link=>A160, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.029]
[5] => [id=>6, nome=>p3.1, link=>A157, quantidade=>1, porcao=>0.103]
[6] => [id=>7, nome=>p3.2, link=>A157, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.021]
[7] => [id=>8, nome=>p4.1, link=>A156, quantidade=>1, porcao=>0.001]
[8] => [id=>8, nome=>p5.1, link=>A161, quantidade=>1, porcao=>0.010]
[9] => [id=>8, nome=>p5.2, link=>A161, quantidade=>2, porcao=>0.100]
`estoqueMovimento`
[0] => [id=>1, senha=>das164, entrada=> 0.400]
[1] => [id=>2, senha=>das162, entrada=> 0.400]
[2] => [id=>3, senha=>das163, entrada=> 0.400]
[3] => [id=>4, senha=>das161, entrada=> 0.400]
[4] => [id=>5, senha=>das165, entrada=> 0.400]
[5] => [id=>6, senha=>das161, entrada=> 0.400]
[6] => [id=>7, senha=>das160, entrada=> 0.400]
[7] => [id=>8, senha=>das165, entrada=> 0.400]
[8] => [id=>9, senha=>das164, entrada=> 0.400]
[9] => [id=>10, senha=>das171, entrada=> 0.400]
[10] => [id=>11, senha=>das160, entrada=> 0.400]
[11] => [id=>12, senha=>das171, entrada=> 0.400]
```

resposta final:

```
[0] => [id=>1, nome=>i1, link=>A156, estoque=>1 receita]
[1] => [id=>2, nome=>i2, link=>A160, estoque=>0.33 receita]
[2] => [id=>3, nome=>i3, link=>A157, estoque=>2 receitas]
[3] => [id=>4, nome=>i4, link=>A156, estoque=>999.56 receitas]
[4] => [id=>5, nome=>i5, link=>, estoque=> 0.200]
[5] => [id=>6, nome=>i6, link=>, estoque=> 0.300]
[6] => [id=>7, nome=>i7, link=>A161, estoque=> 1 receita]
```

navegando pela database ->
i1 -> monta a receita -> entrada/(quantidade*porcao) -> verifica se existe receita dentro de receita e se tiver calcula dinovo o minimo do produto

o lance da recursividade e porque pode ter receita dentro de receita para sempre

consegui chegar ate aqui:

```
SELECT bro.nome,bro.tipo,bro.senha,bro.shanlink,bro.estoqueValido,
                      IF(estoqueValido, 0, bro.minimo) as minimo,
                      IF(estoqueValido, 0, COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida) as estoqueAtual,
                      /*(COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-usr.saida)/(bro.quantidade*bro.porcao) as receita,*/
                      CASE
                        WHEN COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida > bro.minimo THEN 2
                        WHEN COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida <= bro.minimo && COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida > 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END as estoqueStatus
                    FROM estoque as bro
                      LEFT JOIN estoquemovimento as clt ON (bro.senha = clt.senha)
                    GROUP BY bro.senha ORDER BY bro.shanlink DESC, bro.nome ASC
```

Comment: Boas-vindas ao site. É importante **[edit] e adicionar um [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.